# Algorithm to develop an article extractor

Tags: html, css

I have undertaken a project which will extract the main content from any webpage. For example, if I input the URL of any news article, it will return the article part only. The first step would be getting the source code of the given URL. There are many ways to do it. After getting HTML code of given webpage, I will keep the part inside `<body>` tag because obviously article will be somewhere inside body.

After this, I am selecting each `div` element and checking how much text it contains. At end I am selecting the `div` with most text inside it.

Other way I am thinking is, for each `<p>` element, I will check the parent of it. At end, I will select the div which has most `<p>` child directly. To understand it better check this tree- [Tree of an HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tsnI.png)

Now I know that these methods are the basic and that's why I am asking this question. I want to know the suggestions of the community about this. What approaches you all use?

Comment: “Any” webpage is probably over-ambitious, it’s probably a full time work for a whole team at some companies. But you can start by looking at the structure of pages generated by the most common CMSs out there. Many use semantically meaningful HTML tags (e.g. `article`, `section`) or classes which could help a lot. But to generalise you’ll discover that there are many pages where the structure can be quite difficult to guess, and you may need to work by exclusion rather than inclusion in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of implementing your own 'News' crawler...

A few suggestions:

- Check the source ('Right Click' > 'Inspect' at chrome) of some popular sites (e.g. The New York Times); search for common html object names, ids or classes they use to identify the different blocks in the html; for instance: divs with '**story**' or '**story-body**' ids.
- I would go with the word count, but also use a dictionary of common phrases, which are likely to appear in a news article.
- I would search for the block within 'header' and 'footer', excluding comments section or advertisements (again, by searching the values of the object id or class names).
- Start your crawling from the main page, it will probably have references to the sub pages or articles - once you have the reference (e.g. a header or article name), it will help you navigate in the sub page itself.
- In any case, I suggest working with java [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library - it will make your life easier; use it with the jquery-like selectors.

Goodluck.